# How to make no scroll on flex layout

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I have a flex layout with header, footer & 3 columns (main + 2 asides left & right). The task has: "Page should be stretched on full height"  & "Header and Footer should be fixed size, without any stretching (grow/shrink)".

[image]

So I make

```
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;

}    
.heading {
    text-align: center;  
    font-family: sans-serif;
}  
.page {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  &__header,
  &__footer  {    
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 50px;
    flex: none;
  }
  &__blocks {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end; 
    flex-direction: row;
    flex: 1;
  }
}    
.main {

}    
.aside {
  width: 20%;
  &--left {
    background: $aside1-bg-color;
  }
  &--right {
    background: $aside2-bg-color
  }
}
```

but:

1) Page looks bigger than 1 screen height and activate vertical scrolling. How to prevent this & make all the layoute inside 1 screen.

2) my asides actualy does not look like thay are 20% of all width

Please help

Comment: Post complete and compiled code so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you add the HTML source as well? Looks like a perfect example CSS grids (not flexbox).

Comment: @FrankLämmer No more perfect than Flexbox, being a simple 1-dimensional layout.

Comment: Thanks all. Problem was solved with


* { margin:0; }